# Gerar executáveis com nomes diferentes de "a.exe" pelo Sublime Text

Tags: c, windows, sublime-text-2

Eu estou usando o `Sublime Text` para escrever os códigos e deixo eles na área de Trabalho

Toda vez que eu salvo um arquivo `.c`, ele gera um executável para Windows. Quando salvo mais de um código `.c` no desktop e compilo, ele toma o lugar do outro código que fora compilado anteriormente, sempre o mesmo `'a'`.

Como poderia gerar um `'a'` ou executável para cada código `c`.

Comment: Podes mudar o nome a cada `a.exe`. Por exemplo: `a-201603051134.exe` ou `teste-007.exe`, ...

Comment: Não entendi @pmg

Comment: Ja vi que encontraste a solucao do gcc. O que eu estava a dizer era mudares o nome ao executavel: selecciona, carrega F2 e da-lhe um nome diferente. Na proxima compilacao, o compilador gera um `a.exe` diferente.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que estava compilando usando gcc nome_arquivo.c sem o -o que especifica a saída do arquivo.